# Chi-square analysis

Tags: chi-squared-test

Is this a correct analysis for the following statement? ''I enjoy lessons on the computer'' Agree =576 Undecided =77 Disagree =211 chi-square value=463.17 Table value of chi-square at .05 sig is 5.99 Analysis: The chi-square value is greater than the table value at 0.05 level of significance. This shows that the respondents differ in their opinion significantly. Moreover, the majority of the respondents have accepted the statement. Therefore, the statement is accepted.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: An example of the Likert item  is given. My question is that whether this is the correct way to analyze a Likert item with chi-square test?

Comment: To find out what?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find out whether the choices are all equal to 1/3 then you can use chi-square the way you describe, except for your final sentence which really doesn't make much sense here.

However, I think it likely that this is not the question you really want to answer.

Comment: Thanks sir. For example I've only one variable i.e., ''I enjoy lessons on a computer'' I got the responses from the sample (Agree =576 Undecided =77 Disagree =211) ..What statistical test is fit to analyze this variable  to find significant difference among the students' responses.

Comment: With only one variable, there isn't much you can do.  Chi-square looks fine, but it's not a very interesting question.

Comment: I am completely confused.  First you say you have only one variable  Now you have 21 or  so.

Comment: Thanks sir for your quick response, My 5-point Likert Scale questionnaire is divided into 3 constructs. Each construct have 7 or so items. Constructs are (Computer Importance, computer Anxiety, and Computer Enjoyment). My Hypotheses are, ''Students have +ve attitude towards computer technology 2. they give it importance 3 They feel anxiety 4. They enjoy it...''. I want to analyze each construct separately and the constructs as a whole as well to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Sir I was asking only for my understanding. Now its the real matter of my thesis

Comment: Then you need to ask a new question.